# Load a image in JPanel on button click

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have seen many answers regarding this, but nothing seem to solve my problem, I have a jPanel1 and jPanel3 in a tabbed pane (same tab) and when I click a button from jPanel1 then I go to load an image in jPanel3.
Here is how I am trying to do the same

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("In the action");
            try {
                jPanel3.add(new JPanel(){
                    java.net.URL imgURL = this.getClass().getResource( "/resource/images/cd-dvd-icon.png");
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imgURL);
                });
                jPanel3.revalidate();
                jPanel3.repaint();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

But I am not seeing any error or the image also. Please help

Comment: JPanel hasn't constructor for setIcon e.i., etc, have to read Oracle tutorial 2D Graphics

Comment: Changed the code as like below                                      `javax.swing.ImageIcon icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/resource/images/cd-dvd-icon.png");
                javax.swing.JLabel label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
                label.setIcon(icon);
                jPanel3.add(label);
                jPanel3.setSize(50, 50);
                jPanel3.revalidate();
                jPanel3.repaint();
                jPanel3.setVisible(true);` even this does not help

Comment: @Sundhar why don't you post this code into the question? there's a button which says: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23631980/edit) just click it and insert that code inside your question instead of adding it into 10 lines of comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem, have added the layout again as like it is added in the generated code and it worked

```
jButton3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           System.out.println("In the action");
           JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource( "/resource/images/cd-dvd-icon.png")));
            jPanel2.add(imgLabel);
            jPanel2.revalidate();
            jPanel2.repaint();
            jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
            jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addGap(59, 59, 59)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                    .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                    .addComponent(imgLabel)
                    .addContainerGap(235, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                        .addComponent(jButton3))
                        .addGap(59, 59, 59)
                        .addComponent(imgLabel)
                    .addContainerGap(368, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks to all who helped

Answer (score 4):

You're not adding the image to the panel. Create a JLabel with the image inside and then add the label to jPanel3:

```
        try 
        {
            JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource( "/resource/images/cd-dvd-icon.png")));
            jPanel3.add(imgLabel);
            jPanel3.revalidate();
            jPanel3.repaint();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Did a small change in the code that you have provided me `newPanel.add(image);` to `newPanel.add(imgLabel);` because there is no method to add buffered image to a panel and even then I did not work

Comment: This is it `try {
                    java.net.URL imgURL = this.getClass().getResource( "/resource/images/cd-dvd-icon.png");
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imgURL);
                    JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
                    JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                    newPanel.add(imgLabel);
                    jPanel3.add(newPanel);
                    jPanel3.revalidate();
                    jPanel3.repaint();
                } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}});`

Comment: You can make the sample shorter. Label can be directly added to jPanel3, and ImageIcon has constructor with URL as parameter (you should not read it using the ImageIO)

Comment: I verified in Java APIs and made it shorter, thanks Sergiy for hints!

Comment: @mengo and Sergiy Sorry but that was also not working